# Get class name of UIViewController in swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, swift

How do you get the class name of a `UIViewController` class in Swift?

In Objective-C, we can do something like this:

```
self.appDelegate = (shAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    UIViewController *last_screen = self.appDelegate.popScreens.lastObject ;
    
    if(last_screen.class != self.navigationController.visibleViewController.class){

    //.......
}
```

but in Swift I tried:

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
    let last_screen = appDelegate.popScreens?.lastObject as UIViewController
```

Can't do this.

```
if last_screen.class != self.navigationController.visibleViewController.class {

//....

}
```

no `class` method of `UIViewController` i.e last screen

Answer (score 78, accepted):

To know your class name you can call something like this:

```
var className = NSStringFromClass(yourClass.classForCoder)
```

Comment: It returns `<project_name>.<class_name>` but in most cases users need the second part only

Answer (score 64):

The cleanest way without needing to know the name of your class is like this.

```
let name = String(describing: type(of: self))
```

Answer (score 44):

A simple way in swift 3 is to write the below code:

for instances:

```
let className = String(describing: self)
```

for classes:

```
let className = String(describing: YourViewController.self)
```

Comment: Note e.g. `String(describing: UIViewController())` will output `<UIViewController: 0x141d0f7e0>` for example, whereas `String(describing: type(of: UIViewController()))` will just output `UIViewController`

Answer (score 20):

Expanding on juangdelvalle's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28616386/1077789).

I added this as an extension so that it's reusable and easier to call from any view controller. Also in some cases `NSStringFromClass` in Swift returns a string in the format like this:

**< project name >.viewControllerClassName**.

This extension property is modified to get rid of the project name prefix and return only the class name.

```
extension UIViewController {
    var className: String {
        NSStringFromClass(self.classForCoder).components(separatedBy: ".").last!
    }
}
```

Comment: when you say "in some cases" do you mean it doesn't return a consistent answer?

Comment: Actually the first part before the dot is the module name. So if your class is defined in an external library you will see the module name. The last part however should be the real class name. That is unless Apple decide to change this function for some reason.

Comment: why not simply use?

```
let viewControllerName = "\(viewControllerInstance.classForCoder())"
```

Answer (score 8):

Swift 4

Suppose we have class with name `HomeViewController`. Then you can get name of class with the following code:

```
let class_name = "\(HomeViewController.classForCoder())"
```

The `classForCoder()` method returns `AnyClass` object (name of your class) which we convert to string for user.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a swift3 version of isuru's answer.

```
extension UIViewController {
    var className: String {
        return NSStringFromClass(self.classForCoder).components(separatedBy: ".").last!;
    }
}
```

Comment: There's an extra ';' in the end.

Comment: :) @alasker . guess I'm not a swift developer at heart.

Answer (score 6):

Swift 5 solution:

```
extension NSObject {
  var className: String {
    return String(describing: type(of: self))
  }

  class var className: String {
    return String(describing: self)
  }
}
```

USAGE:

```
class TextFieldCell: UITableVIewCell {
}

class LoginViewController: UIViewController {
  let cellClassName = TextFieldCell.className
}
```

Answer (score 3):

We can also do: `String(describing: Self.self)` in Swift 5.1.

Answer (score 2):

Use `String.init(describing: self.classForCoder)`

example:

```
let viewControllerName = String.init(describing: self.classForCoder)
print("ViewController Name: \(viewControllerName)")
```

Answer (score 1):

The property is called `dynamicType` in Swift.

Comment: Note: this property was deprecated a while ago and is fully phased out in the latest Swift at least

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
    extension NSObject {

    static var stringFromType: String? {
        return NSStringFromClass(self).components(separatedBy: ".").last
    }

    var stringFromInstance: String? {
        return NSStringFromClass(type(of: self)).components(separatedBy: ".").last
    }
}
```